# Recursive function not behaving correctly

Tags: powershell, recursion

We have the following structure in active directory for group memberships:

```
BEL Test Top level
    - BEL Test Sub  level 1
        - Bob
        - BEL Test Sub  level 1.1
            - Jake
            - Mike
    - BEL Test Sub  level 2
        - BEL Test Sub  level 2.1
```

**The desired output:**

```
GroupName : BEL Test Top level
Member1   : BEL Test Sub  level 1
Member2   : BEL Test Sub  level 1.1
Member3   : Jake

GroupName : BEL Test Top level
Member1   : BEL Test Sub  level 1
Member2   : BEL Test Sub  level 1.1
Member3   : Mike

GroupName : BEL Test Top level
Member1   : BEL Test Sub  level 1
Member2   : Bob

GroupName : BEL Test Top level
Member1   : BEL Test Sub  level 2
Member2   : BEL Test Sub  level 2.1
```

So for every deepest object there needs to be a `[PSCustomObject]` as output. I'm not such an expert in recursive functions, but the following code I made comes very close:

```
$Name = 'BEL Test Top level'

$hash = $null

Function Add-MemberGroupHC {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        $Identity,
        $Past,
        [Int]$Level
    )

    Begin {
        if (-not $Level) {
            $Level = 0
        }

        if (-not $Past) {
            $Past = [Ordered]@{
                GroupName = $Name
            }
        }

        if ($Identity.GetType().Name -ne 'ADPrincipal') {
            $Identity = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Identity
        }
    }

    Process {
        $Level++

        Write-Verbose "Check members '$($Identity.Name)'"

        $Members = Get-ADGroupMember $Identity 

        $Members | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Verbose "Add property '$('Member' + $Level)' value '$($_.Name)'"
            $Past.('Member' + $Level) = $_.Name

            if (($_.ObjectClass -eq 'User') -or (-not (Get-ADGroupMember $_))) {
                  [PSCustomObject]$Past
            }
                $Past.('Member' + $Level) = $_.Name
                [PSCustomObject]$Past
            }

            if ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group') {
                Add-MemberGroupHC -Identity $_ -Past $Past -Level $Level
            }
        }

    }
}

$Result = Add-MemberGroupHC $Name
$Result | fl *
```

How is it possible to have it output only the deepest levels when calling itself when there are no children anymore?

Comment: What is your current Output? Also I think you are missing an `else` or have an extra bracket in your second last if block. Probably a copy paste mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to take my own approach to learn how this works from the start. I cannot say if this is better or worse than your intended approach. Hopefully you can use this to see where you might have gone wrong.

```
Function Get-HighestMemberKey{
    param([hashtable]$HashTable)

    # Collect all of the member# names. Find the highest one. 
    # If one does not exist null gets cast to 0 with [int]
    return [int](($HashTable.GetEnumerator()) | 
        Select -ExpandProperty Name | 
        Where-Object{$_ -match "(\d+)$"} |
        ForEach-Object{$Matches[0]} |
        Measure-Object -Maximum | 
        Select -ExpandProperty Maximum)
}

function Get-ADMembersGroupChain{
    param(
        $GroupName,
        $CurrentChain
    )

    $CurrentMembers = @(Get-ADGroupMember $GroupName)

    # Check if this group has any members.
    if($CurrentMembers.Count -gt 0){
        # If there are any groups process them individually
        $CurrentMembers | ForEach-Object{

            if(!$CurrentChain){
                # This is a root group. Start a new chain.
                $CurrentChain = @{GroupName=$GroupName}
            }

            # Add this member to the chain. 
            # Create a new chain for this pass. Use clone to ensure we are working with a new chain. 
            $nextMemberIndex = (Get-HighestMemberKey $CurrentChain) + 1
            $newChain = $CurrentChain.Clone()
            $newChain."Member$nextMemberIndex" = $_.Name

            # If this is a group continue the chain. 
            if($_.ObjectClass -eq "group"){
                Get-ADMembersGroupChain -GroupName $_.SamAccountName -CurrentChain $newChain
            } else {
                # This is a user. Output the chain
                [pscustomobject]$newChain
            }
        }
    } else {
        # The group is already part of the chain. Ouput as is. 
        [pscustomobject]$CurrentChain
    }
}

$chains = Get-ADMembersGroupChain "BEL Test Top level" 
$chains | ForEach-Object{$_| fl}
```

What we do here is build hashtables that are passed recursively to the function. When a group is encountered the function is called again. If there is ever a group with 0 members or if a user is found the chain thus far is converted to a psobject and sent down the pipe.

There is one small side effect with this as you cannot guarentee the order that the members get displayed. You will see to build your own select statement for that if this is an issue.

---

### Sample output

```
GroupName : BEL Test Top level
Member3   : Jake
Member1   : BEL Test Sub  level 1
Member2   : BEL Test Sub  level 1.1

GroupName : BEL Test Top level
Member3   : Mike
Member1   : BEL Test Sub  level 1
Member2   : BEL Test Sub  level 1.1

GroupName : BEL Test Top level
Member1   : BEL Test Sub  level 1
Member2   : Bob

GroupName : BEL Test Top level
Member1   : BEL Test Sub  level 2
Member2   : BEL Test Sub  level 2.1
```

Without using `Format-List`, like you have done the output might not appear correct, as PowerShell will display based on the first object in the pipe, but all of the properties will be there. If this is an issue then you need to create a small function to guarantee the order of property output. A basic example would be:

```
function Order-Chain{
    param(
        $chain
    )

    # Take the group and members and ensure the are output in numerical order. 
    # Assume there is at least a property called GroupName
    $properties = @("GroupName")
    # Get all the remaining property names minus the first one.
    $properties += $chain.psobject.properties.name | Where-Object{$_ -notin $properties} | 
        # Sort the property list on the number at the end of the property name
        Sort-Object -Property {[void]($_ -match "\d+$");$matches[0]}

    # Order the chain and send down the pipe
    $chain | Select-Object $properties
}
```

That will create a sorted property list that is fed to `Select-Object`. It might seem smarter / easier to use `[ordered]` when creating the hashtable but you cannot clone an ordered hash so this is the way I got around it.

All of the functions here could be made more robust, i.e. use the `begin` block like you have, and into advanced functions but function correctly now. **Beware** of circular groups as there is no logic to detect those.

Comment: @DarkLite1 I added something to make up for PowerShells behavior in this matter. I will look at your function now to see if I can figure out what happened.

Comment: Thx Matt! I always wonder why your code looks so much more professional than mine... Gonna have to play catch-up for a while. Following a Java course now to bridge some gaps in logical thinking. Thx man, appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on circular groups. I will add some checks to the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post how I finally fixed my erroneous code. Thx to @Matt for the great help. Below is the full code with a check for circular group membership.

Hope this helps anyone stumbling on the same or a similar problem as me.

```
Function Get-ADGroupMemberFlatHC {
<# 
    .SYNOPSIS   
        Get AD group membership and create an object for eash deepest AD Object.

    .DESCRIPTION
        Retrieve all the members of an active directory group. When a group doesn't contain any members we output this group. If it does contain other members we output only the users and do the same for group members. In the end, the output will contain one object per deepeest node, which can be an AD group or AD user.

    .PARAMETER Identity 
        The group name in Strng format or ADPrincipal format #>

    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        $Identity
    )

    Begin {
        Function Add-MemberGroupHC {
            Param (
                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                $Identity,
                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                $Past,
                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                [Int]$Level
            )

            Process {
                Write-Verbose "Check members '$($Identity.Name)'"
                $Past = Remove-ExcessHashItemsHC $Past ('Member' + ($Level+1))

                Get-ADGroupMember $Identity | ForEach-Object {
                    $Past.('Member' + ($Level+1)) = $_.Name

                    if ($CircularGroup = Test-CircularGroupMembershipHC $Past) {
                        $CircularGroup
                    }
                    else {
                        if (($_.ObjectClass -eq 'User') -or (-not (Get-ADGroupMember $_))) {
                            Write-Verbose "End node '$($_.Name)'"
                            [PSCustomObject]$Past
                        }
                        elseif ($_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group') {
                            Write-Verbose "Member group '$($_.Name)'"
                            Add-MemberGroupHC -Identity $_ -Past $Past -Level ($Level+1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Function Remove-ExcessHashItemsHC {
            Param (
                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                [hashtable]$HashTable,
                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                [String]$Key
            )

            $OrderedHashTable = [Ordered]@{}

            $HashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | where Name -LT $Key | ForEach-Object {
                $OrderedHashTable.($_.Name) = $_.Value
            }

            $OrderedHashTable
        }

        Function Test-CircularGroupMembershipHC {
            Param (
                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                [HashTable]$HastTable
            )

            $HastTable.Values | Group-Object | where Count -GE 2 | ForEach-Object {
                Write-Warning "Circular group memberships found for group '$($_.Name)'"
                $Past[$Past.Count -1] = ($Past[-1] + ' *')
                [PSCustomOBject]$Past
            }
        }
    }

    Process {
        Try {
            $Past = [Ordered]@{}

            if ($Identity.GetType().Name -ne 'ADPrincipal') {
                $Identity = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Identity
            }

            Write-Verbose "Add property 'GroupName' value '$($Identity.Name)'"
            $Past.GroupName = $Identity.Name

            Add-MemberGroupHC -Identity $Identity -Past $Past -Level 0
        }
        Catch {
            throw "Failed retrieving members for group '$Identity': $_"
        }
    }
}
```